# Join on field vs join on subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

Good morning.

I was wondering what it's more optimized:

```
SELECT PROD.ID
FROM PRODUCT PROD
INNER JOIN SUBPRODUCT SUB ON PROD.SUBTYPE = SUB.SUBTYPE AND SUB.SOMEFIELD = 1
WHERE PROD.FOO = 2
```

OR

```
SELECT PROD.ID
FROM PRODUCT PROD
INNER JOIN 
( 
 SELECT SUB.SUBTYPE FROM SUBPRODUCT SUB WHERE SUB.SOMEFIELD = 1
) PROD.SUBTYPE = SUB.SUBTYPE
WHERE PROD.FOO = 2
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Should be 1st one, but to know for sure look at execution plan. Also your syntax for subquery is wrong. You are missing `ON` statement

Comment: You need to learn to look at the execution plans for queries to answer this type of question.  That said, I would expect SQL Server's optimizer to produce the same execution plans for these two queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by looking at the query,I can not tell which one is more optimized form. But I will go with the below one.

```
SELECT PROD.ID
FROM PRODUCT PROD
INNER JOIN 
( 
 SELECT SUB.SUBTYPE FROM SUBPRODUCT SUB WHERE SUB.SOMEFIELD = 1
) T ON PROD.SUBTYPE = T.SUBTYPE
WHERE PROD.FOO = 2
```